# Cross Compiling for arm with dependencies on Shared Object which are only available for x86-64

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I am working at a Robot Communication system. This System runs on Ubuntu. To get a working communication I need to install a debian package which installs a library with shared objects.
I want to get that working on an ARM-device. I can not install the debian-package on the ARM-device. I am thinking about trying to cross compile the binary. The Problem is that it depends on binaries for x86-64. Is there any way to still get the executable working on the ARM-device?

For compiling I am using a cmake file which loos like this (without cross-compiling):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(dummy_service)

find_package(XXX)
include_directories(${XXX_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${XXX_LIBRARY_DIR})

XXX_message_library(
  TARGET XXX_messages
  DIRECTORY msg
  STATIC)

add_executable(dummy_service src/dummy_service.c++)

target_link_libraries(dummy_service ${XXX_LIBRARY} dummy_messages)
```

As the XXX library is not owned by our company and not public, I am not allowed to talk about it, but I could answers questions if you have any.
The debian package includes following objects:

```
-bin
--xxx-gen 
--xxx-core 
--xxx-master

-include
--headerfiles
---xxx.h
---types.h
---internal
----utilities.h
----descriptors.h
----logging.h
----master.h
----service.h

-lib
--libxxx.so
--cmake
---.cmake files
```

Comment: `that it depends on binaries for x86-64. Is there any way to still get the executable working on the ARM-device?` So cross-compile these libraries for ARM, then link with the crosscompiled version.. My simplest setup is cross-machine container in docker with binfmt-auto and qemu-static. `I am not allowed to talk about it, but I could answers questions` :D

Comment: OK, got it. So, here is my question: What is `XXX`? ;-)

Comment: Do you have the source of XXX ? Is it using a CMake build-system ?
you can try to run an arm qemu to emulate a x86_64 cpu so you could run the x86_64 binary on your ARM target

Comment: As far as I understand, these libaries use the binaries from the debian Package. And I think I can not cross-compile them, or can I? 
All I have is the debian package-

@Mizux I have the mentioned debian package. The Problem is that it includes already compiled binaries. 

The debian package is the xxx libary. I edited my Question for more clarity.

Comment: my point is if you had the sources, you may have use it using FetchContent() instead of find_package() thus if using a cross toolchain file you'll also build (all) your third parties making the cross compilation easier since you embedded everything  (except a basic sysroot)...